# Como salvar um csv utilizando hibernate e mysql

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, hibernate, jpa

Preciso que seja feito a seguinte rotina:

1. Ler algumas informações do banco de dados;
2. Gerar um csv com base nesses dados;
3. Gravar esse csv no banco de dados;
4. Iniciar o download desse arquivo para o usuário.

Eu consegui fazer os itens 1 e 2, gerando o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("c:\\test.csv");
writer.append("user");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Indo para o item 3. Defini o campo no banco como BLOB e na entidade como `byte[];` Como converto o objeto `FileWriter` para byte?

A respeito do item 4 pretendo utilizar o `p:fileDownload` do Primefaces. Porém o mesmo espera um `StreamedContent`, ou seja. Terei que realizar uma nova conversão!

Posso estar errado em alguma dessas anotações. E peço a ajuda de todos para resolver este problema!

Comment: Limite a pergunta a um problema específico e forneça detalhes suficientes para conseguir uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Obrigado pela edição. Achas que devo fornecer mais o que para conseguir uma resposta adequada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após várias consultas na internet. Consegui achar uma solução...

1. Gere o csv utilizando o StringBuilder. Exemplo:

   ```
   StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
   csv.append("USER");
   ```
2. Salve o csv na sua entidade mapeada (lembrando que o tipo do campo da entidade deve ser byte[] e no banco de dados deve ser BLOB.

   ```
   ExportData exportData = new ExportData();
   exportData.setFile(csv.toString().getBytes());
   ```
3. Recupere a informação no banco e faça a conversão para o StreamedContent.

   ```
   private StreamedContent file;

   file = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(exportDataService.exportData()), "csv", "export.csv");
   ```
4. Gera os gets e sets do file, para poder obter no xhtml.
5. Insira um commandButton com fileDownload, utilizando o **actionListener**. Se tentar utilizar o action o valor só será populado após a segunda iteração.

   ```
   <p:commandButton value="Export Data" ajax="false"
                    actionListener="#{listaExportMB.exportData()}"                                       
                    styleClass="btn-info"
                    icon="fa fa-cloud-download">
       <p:fileDownload value="#{listaExportMB.file}"/>                         
   </p:commandButton>
   ```